# How to make a button show a table onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to embed a table inside a button to no avail, such that when the button is clicked the table shows and when it is clicked again, the table disappears. Here is a copy of my code:

```js
function myfunction(){    
  document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display = "none";   
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Button1" onclick='myfunction();'>
<div id="displaytable" style="visibility: hidden">
  <table id="displaytable" style="display: none; width: 100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="lbl">column1</td>
      <td class="lbl">column2</td>
      <td class="lbl">column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: You want a simple toggle function. Inside your function check for the current state of the table, if it is displayed or not, and then set the opposite.

Comment: Ive provided both a jquery and javascript solution and btw you need to make another update, remove the "display:none" from your table and replace visibility:hidden to display:none in your div as shown in my code.

Comment: Is it possible to do this for menus in a drop down list as they only seem to accept links

Answer (score 2):

You should change the `ID` of your input to another `ID`, and then your function just need to be as below:

```
function myfunction()
{
    if (document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display === "none")
        document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display="block";
    else
        document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display="none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This a bit rework on your code. Vanilla only. HTML is just a bit different, with some new id's.

```
<input id="toggleVisibilityButton" type="button" value="Button1"/>
<table  id="displaytable" style="display:none" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
            <td class="lbl">column1</td>
            <td class="lbl">column2</td>
            <td class="lbl">column3</td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="center">1</td>
            <td align="center">2</td>
             <td align="center">33</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center">4</td>
            <td align="center">5</td>
           <td align="center">6</td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

And JS I kept as simple as possible, since I assume you are the beginner and don't need something more elegant:

```
document.getElementById("toggleVisibilityButton").addEventListener("click", function(button) {    
   if (document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display === "none")             document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display = "block";
   else document.getElementById("displaytable").style.display = "none";
});
```

You can test it here:
[fiddle JS](https://jsfiddle.net/coh63L40/3/)

**NOTE:**

I changed the way you bind your actions to elements. You are trying to do it directly from HTML and on to a function that you haven't stored as variable. This is not the best practice.

Instead I followed an approach referred to as:
[Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: In your fiddleJS sample when I clicked on button it doesn't disappear the table!

Comment: @MiladRashidi Works perfectly for me. I updated just in case.

Comment: I linked the wrong fiddleJS. It's missing the toggle code it only switches table to be displayed. My bad

Comment: Now it's seems like my solution and it is working correctly.

Comment: Glad you went with vanilla also. Add a lib cause of 2 liner. Why not put angular on top just so you can toggle button :D

Comment: It's a simple changing on property in DOM element done via vanilla JS. Every displayable element should work with this. What do you mean by they only accept links?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the list of answers , you can always use `classList` web API to solve this problem.

You just have to write a class , say

```
hide{
display:none;
}
```

and toggle it with the `toggle` method of `element.classList` like

```
  tableelement.classList.toggle('hidden')
```

a fiddle can be seen here

```js
var click = document.getElementById('clickme');
click.addEventListener('click', myfunction);

function myfunction() {
  var tablewrap = document.getElementById('displaytable');
  tablewrap.classList.toggle('hidden')
};
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.placeholder {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="displaytable" class="placeholder">
  <table id="displaytable2" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" border="3">
    <tr align="center">
      <td class="lbl">column1</td>
      <td class="lbl">column2</td>
      <td class="lbl">column3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">1</td>
      <td align="center">2</td>
      <td align="center">33</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">4</td>
      <td align="center">5</td>
      <td align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="button" id="clickme" value="Show/Hide" />
</div>
```

Further reading here [classList web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)